# Chrome user stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, stylesheet

Just trying out Cloud9 IDE (in-browser ide http://c9.io) and I'm confused.
Colors in Terminal window are broken, but only in Chrome.
Firefox (and even Opera) have no such problems.

After some research in Chrome dev tools I've figured that styles are overriden by "user stylesheet".
I know about "user agent stylesheet", but with user stylesheet I can't even disable it.

How do I edit/disable it?

https://jumpshare.com/v/uoXqtLt0rNsmd7rW2SBS?b=VDG49PYVOjsApHrgFrQw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encoutered exactly the same problem, with Google Chrome and the ACE editor. I found that I have installed the "stylebot" Chrome extension some time ago and when I disable this extension, ACE behaves "normally".

Stylebot extension added "user stylesheet" in this path, which may have changed behaviour of many 3rd party libraries such as ACE editor:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha\2.1_0\libs\
```

You may disable the Stylebot extension or edit it's CSS files manually.